# how to categorize a column into two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like this:

| ID | Type | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Q001 | In | 2022-8-30 08:30:00 |
| Q001 | Out | 2022-8-30 10:35:00 |
| Q001 | In | 2022-8-30 10:42:00 |
| Q001 | Out | 2022-8-30 12:15:00 |

I want to get result like this:

| ID | In | out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Q001 | 2022-8-30 08:30:00 | 2022-8-30 10:35:00 |
| Q001 | 2022-8-30 10:42:00 | 2022-8-30 12:15:00 |

I think maybe I can use two sub-tables for in and out data ordered by id and time,then create a table with same index of each table,like below

```
 select  Intable.id,
         Intable.time,
         Outtable.time 
 from (select * from T1
       where type='IN' order by ID, Time  as Intable) 
 join ( select * from T1
         where type='out' as Outtable order by ID, Time) 
 where Intable.ID = Outtable.id
```

Is this possible? And how do I get from each table with same index? Thx.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

To get your desired results you can use a query like this

```
SELECT
    id,
    MIN(time) AS "in",
    MAX(time) AS out
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY time) rn
    FROM t1
) t
GROUP BY id, rn
```

Or another

```
SELECT
    id,
    (SELECT 
         MAX(time) 
     FROM t1 t_in
     WHERE t_in.id = t1.id 
           AND t_in.type = 'In'
           AND t_in.time < t1.time
    ) "in",
    time "out"
FROM t1
WHERE type = 'Out'
```

Both queries produces the same results

| id | in | out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Q001 | 2022-08-30 08:30:00.000 | 2022-08-30 10:35:00.000 |
| Q001 | 2022-08-30 10:42:00.000 | 2022-08-30 12:15:00.000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f0998b67d83bee777866a520b8b943ed)*